# Database Failures With Better Hosting

Tags: mysql, load, hosting, jmeter

I am developing a php mysql app that is currently on a shared server at Host Gator.

I decided to do some load testing with Apache JMeter to see how many transactions (SQL insert on table with no auto-increment value) would fail under high load (1,000 concurrent threads).

I was surprised to see it be over 20%.

If i moved from a share host to a dedicated host (just myself), can I expect this number to go down?

The transaction I was testing was just an insert into a table with three fields (no auto increment values). table type is InnoDB

Comment: It should go down because the number of concurrent threads can be higher because of more CPU and other factors that effect speed.

Comment: thats what I assumed; error rate was getting very high when I did 100+ concurrences. I'm curious to see what results I get when I do migrate over. Thank!

Comment: Your welcome.  I'll add answer (with my comment) so that this question is "solved".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should go down because the number of concurrent threads can be higher because of more CPU and other factors that effect speed.